# Could not initialize proxy - no Session spring boot and javafx

Tags: java, spring, javafx, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot and Javafx.

Yesterday i found this https://github.com/thomasdarimont/spring-labs/tree/master/spring-boot-javafx and add only Spring JPA to my pom.xml and configuration to application.properties.

POM

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.18</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Application.properties

```
app.ui.title=Spring Boot Java FX Hello World
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://mysql0.xxx/3450_ps15\?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username = xxx
spring.datasource.password = xxx
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

I spend many hours for trying to fix this error. On all entity i must use `FetchType.EAGER` otherwise i get this error. I have 3600 records taking from db take many houres in EAGER. I was trying to add `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` in service implementation and repository. This is my code, maybe i forgot something.
Service

```
public interface ProductService {
    Page<ProductPS> findAll(Pageable pageable); 
    List<ProductPS> findAll();
    Long getCount();
}
```

Repository

```
@Transactional  
public interface ProductRepository extends Repository<ProductPS, Long>{
    @Transactional
    @Query("Select p from ProductPS p inner join p.productlang lang where lang.lang.id=1")
    Page<ProductPS> findAll(Pageable pageable); 
    @Query("Select p from ProductPS p inner join p.productlang lang where lang.lang.id=1")
    List<ProductPS> findAll();
    Long count();
}
```

Service Implementation

```
@Component
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
@Service
public class ProductServiceImp implements ProductService{
        @Autowired
        private ProductRepository productrepository;
        @Autowired
        public ProductServiceImp(ProductRepository productrepository) {
            this.productrepository = productrepository;
        }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public Page<ProductPS> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
         if (!TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()) {
               throw new IllegalStateException("No active transaction!!!!");
            }
        return productrepository.findAll(pageable);
    }
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<ProductPS> findAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return productrepository.findAll();
    }
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Long getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return productrepository.count();
    }

}
```

And Entity

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1804619891680745433L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id_product")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="id_category_default")
    private int idCategoryDefault;
    private float price;
    private String reference;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private List<StockPS> stock;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "produkt")
    private List<ProductLangPS> productlang;
```

I'm using `hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans` but this only take some records and when i scroll in tableview take next but this take to many time. I've added

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
```

in config and transaction is working but it doesn't not me. This is bug or i miss something? Is it possible to set session manually in Spring Data?
If some on say use pagination i was try

```
private Node createPage(int pageIndex) {


        int fromIndex = pageIndex * 50;
        int toIndex = (int) Math.min(fromIndex + 50, productService.getCount());
        Pageable topTen = new PageRequest(fromIndex, toIndex);
        table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(productService.findAll(topTen).getContent()));

        return table;
    }
```

on next page return no records. This return only from 0 to n.

Comment: What is "this error"?

Comment: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ProductPS.productlang, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: You get this exception because the hibernate session is already closed when you try to access the nested collection.
I'd recommend to structure you application in a way that ensures that the nested associations are populated before they are used, e.g. by using a dedicated service layer that loads the data from a datastore through a repository and prepares / initializes the structure for sending it to the client.

I created a prototypic example application that demonstrates this: https://github.com/thomasdarimont/spring-labs/tree/example/spring-boot-javafx-jpa/spring-boot-javafx-jpa-demo

Comment: @ThomasDarimont thx for spend time and create this prototype application. I think i have to many records to  get from db beacuse i still getting Could not initialize proxy - no Session. I will be use hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans  and pagination for 100 records i have small lag only. Thomas i can use mysql limit in spring using PageRequest?